# Apache Karaf usage

Tags: apache-karaf, hotdeploy

I am very new to Apache Karaf. I have a Java program packaged in a `jar` file, say `A-1.0.jar`. I have also a Karaf instance in which I have deployed `A.jar` under `deploy` folder. Now I am running this `jar` using:

```
java -jar A.jar
```

it prints few numbers on screen. While this is running I deployed `A-2.0.jar` in the same path (`deploy` folder under Karaf home). From Karaf logs, I can see that Karaf has already installed both bundles.

My question is, while running `A-1.0.jar`, is Karaf supposed to execute `A-2.0.jar` (since Karaf got this new version) now onwards? Or, I am missing something? How can I test Karaf's hot-deployment strategy?

Thanks in advance,

Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

At last got some understanding...

Any custom `jar` execution has no relation with Karaf, it does not even know about execution (since they are two separate JVM instance).

We need to write a `BundleActivator` within the `jar` which invokes the actual code, then deploy it in Karaf (or put it under `deploy` folder) and start it. Karaf automatically invokes `BundleActivator` hence our custom code gets executed.

A `jar` is always uniquely identified by `Bundle-SymbolicName` in `MANIFEST` file (`jar` file name does not matter). Also `Bundle-Version` signifies the actual version. If `A-1.0.jar` and `A-2.0.jar` have same name then Karaf assumes later as latest version of same `jar` that it was executing (`A-1.0.jar`). So once found, it automatically executes `A-2.0.jar` once the `A-1.0.jar`'s execution completes.